# How to access nested template parameters that are enums?

Tags: c++, templates, enums, nested

Say I have a class template taking an enum parameter, `A` below. And I have another class template, `B`. And I instantiate an object of `B` specialized on `A` as in the code shown here:

```
enum class Colours { red, green, blue };

template <Colours C>
class A {};

template <typename T>
class B {};

B<A<Colours::red>> myObj;
```

How can I access the colour `C` within the definition of `B`?

Thanks!

I liked SergeyA's answer and have provided this fully worked example here.

```
#include <iostream>
enum class Colours { red, green, blue };

template <auto C> // vscode complains about the use of auto here
class A {
 public:
  static constexpr auto value = C;
};

template <typename T>
class B {
 public:
  int operator()() { return static_cast<int>(T::value); }
};

B<A<Colours::red>> red;
B<A<Colours::green>> green;
B<A<Colours::blue>> blue;

int main() {
  std::cout << red() << ", " << green() << ", " << blue() << std::endl;
  // 0, 1, 2
}
```

This compiles & runs with g++8 -std=c++17. I'm amazed at what you can do with `auto` :-)

Comment: `template<enum E>` is not valid C++ (at least, not the construction seem to be using it as). Please edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Do you want that `E` is the type `Colours` or the value `Colours::red` represents?

Comment: I want the value of the enum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Adding a using E = E; line to A doesn't compile.

Indeed it does not. But you can do something like this:

```
template <auto E_>
class A {
    public: static constexpr auto E = E_;
};
```

which compiles and works as expected. This assumes C++17.

Comment: I think `public: static constexpr auto E = E_;` here, if you want other classes to be able to see it.

Comment: @NathanPierson valid observation, I failed to notice it is `class`.